# Adding QFrame A to layout of QGroupBox B when QFrame is instantiated outside QGroupBox

Tags: c++, qt

I encountered an unwanted behavior when adding a QFrame in a QVboxLayout of a QGroupBox.

I have a custom QFrame class :

```
class CustomFrame : public QFrame
{

}
```

I have a class `CustomGb` that inherits `QGroupBox` with a method `addFrame` that is supposed to add a type A frame to the groupBox's layout

```
class CustomGb: public QGroupBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        CustomGb();
        ~CustomGb();

        void addCustomFrame(CustomFrame* aFrame);

   private:       
        QVBoxLayout * _timeLayout;     
}

CustomGb::CustomGb()
{
    _timeLayout=new QVBoxLayout;
    setLayout(_timeLayout);
}

CustomGb::addCustomFrame(customFrame * aFrame)
{
    _timeLayout->addWidget(aFrame);
}
```

I want to add a new frame in my groupbox.

I naturally call this code (1st algo) :

```
  CustomFrame * aFrame = new CustomFrame ();
  CutomGbInstance.addCustomFrame(aFrame );
```

This results in my frame not being added correctly in the group box. It's added in top left corner. And calling this code several times will note add frames below each other but every frame will be in the exact same place. It's like the frames are not even in the layout.
[image: Unwanted Behavior]

However when i call this instead (2nd algo):

```
  CustomFrame * aFrame = new CustomFrame ();
  CustomGbInstance.layout()->addWidget(highLevelAlertFrame);
```

It works fine.  Calling this code several times will result in several frame perfectly vertically aligned in my groupBox.
[image: WantedBehavior]

Calling the `QVboxLayout::addWidget(QWidget *)` method in the scope where I instantiated my frame gives me what i want. But if I call the `QVboxLayout::addWidget(QWidget *)` method in a different scope with the `QWidget *` passed through another method for example (like with my `addCustomFrame` method) it behaves weirdly.

I Attached 2 pictures :

First one is the unwanted behavior (with 1st algo 3 times), second one is what I want (and what I get when calling 2nd algo 3 times).

Comment: Works fine for me. You are not overriding any paint events, are you?

Comment: I don't think so. I forgot to say that I just upgraded to Qt 5.5. Maybe it's relevant.

Comment: that's unlikely. Here's the code I've tried (almost copy-pasted from your question, I just added 2 lined for the color of CustomFrame) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eb87a7a24ecb6b9764ad and here is the result http://imgur.com/54u4L4F I'm also using Qt 5.5.

Comment: I cleaned up my project files and called qmake again and now it's working just fine... I didn't get to the bottom of it. Anyway thanks

Comment: Np. Voting to close, since the problem was resolved by itself.

Comment: I finally found out what was wrong : I was setting the QFrame in two different layouts. The second one was not properly set on the GroupBox hence the erratic behavior. This second layout was only use is the "addCustomFrame".